# Image is not uploading after submiting form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When I'm trying to upload a user profile picture using form, which allowing users to edit their account information - nothing is happening.

I'm not sure what should I do, to get this upload working.

**models.py**:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = (
        'image',
    )
```

**views.py**:

```
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
else:
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

**settings.py**:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mainapp/media')
```

**edit-profile.html**:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload files(include images) to Django View, you should get FILES from `request.FILES`. so like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)

    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        data.user = request.user
        data.save()
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
```

Comment: I tried it, but still nothing is happening with selected image after submitting a form.

Comment: @rchtp Updated answer. check this:)

Comment: @Boemi Unfortunately, still nothing :(

Comment: if you `print(form)` after `form.is_valid()`, how does it shows?

Comment: This is a result: <tr><th><label for="id_image">Image:</label></th><td><input id="id_image" name="image" type="file" /></td></tr>

Comment: Interesting fact is that result not include a "value" parameter. Do you know why? And thanks for help BTW :)

Comment: how about add enctype='multipart/form-data' to form field?

Comment: Still not working... Another value, as for example CharField is getting updated by the form, and sending a "value" parameter. I don't know why it's not working with ImageField.

Comment: I feel very stupid, edited different template which I used for testing (of course not assigned with a view). Everything works beautifully with proper one, thanks Beomi!